# Is there any way to store data when writing Roslyn analyzers or VS extensions?

Tags: roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

i am writing a Roslyn analyzer and i need to store some data, and so my analyzers can share data between them. Or i want to save the state of my analyzer and again i want to save some data to a db or write to a file. Is there any option to store data while using Analyzer with Code fix template?

Comment: Do you want to share data between your analyzer or between your analyzer and a code fix? I would avoid any kind of persistence that isn't inherently tied to the lifetime of your diagnostic: making a db roundtrip every time an analyzer is called will most likely be hugely expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no easy API to share state across analyzer instances. We are discussing adding such a feature in [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/6324). However, what that API would do can simply be achieved by you having a type that exposes a static ConditionalWeakTable and store your data there and share that across your analyzers. You do need to be careful to make sure that you are not leaking compilations.

The analyzer produced by the template is a portable library project and so doesn't have access to many of the file\db APIs. You could convert your analyzer to be a project that targets .NET 4.5.2 and then use those APIs. However, I'd strongly recommend avoiding that if possible for two reason - one is that the analyzers will be executed on every keystroke in VS and making a db call that often would degrade perf. The second is that non-portable analyzer will be specific to VS and won't be able to run for ASP.NET 5 or .NET CLI

Answer (score 2):

ability to share resources between analyzers will be added by the issue @Srivatsn Narayanan mentioned. but that doesn't mean you can share state.

for state to be useful between analyzers, you need some kind of dependency or execution ordering guarantee between analyzers which don't exist.

PS:
you can ask adding support for such guarantee but since that will make whole system way more complex, and there is a workaround author can do himself (by creating one analyzer and do everything there itself) probably won't be supported any time soon.

Comment: by the way, analyzer currently is not designed to write something back to system. it only read something from the context (system) and only output it can generate is diagnostic.

if you want to change something into system, you need code fix, and it must be explicitly invoked by users.

since analyzer, depending on host, can run in any order and without any user explicit action, analyzer is not good place to writing anything out.